# How to attach several files in mail using unix command?

Tags: mysql, email, ubuntu, sendmail, ubuntu-14.04

I'm implementing a script to backup my MySQL database. All process is OK and I send an email when it finish. But I want to attach the file in that email and I don't know how to do it.

My command line is:

```
mail -s "$1" -a "MIME-Version: 1.0;" -a "Content-type: text/html;" root@$domain -c ops@mydomain.com < $2
```

Where `$1 = My subject` and `$2 = my message body`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. You can use `mail` command to send 1 attachment as follow (you'd better TAR / ZIP your files before sending):

```
echo "$2" | mail -s "$1" -a /path/to/file.tar.gz ops@mydomain.com
```

Next, if you want to have more features, you can use `mutt` (install with `apt-get install mutt`):

```
mutt -s "$1" -a /path/to/file1.tar.gz -a /path/to/file2.tar.gz -a /path/to/file3.tar.gz ops@mydomain.com < /tmp/mailbody.txt
```

where:

- file1.tar.gz to file3.tar.gz are file attachments
- ops@mydomain.com is recipient
- mailbody.txt is the contents of email

or use `uuencode` (install with `apt-get install sharutils`):

```
uuencode /path/to/file.tar.gz /path/to/file.tar.gz | mailx -s "$1" ops@mydomain.com
```

Note:

- you have to repeat the `file.tar.gz` twice (read [uuencode documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uuencode) for more information)
- `mailx` is a newer version of `mail`, but still an ancient command

to send multiple attachments with `mail` command (well, if you insist):

```
$ uuencode file1.tar.gz file1.tar.gz > /tmp/out.mail
$ uuencode file2.tar.gz file3.tar.gz >> /tmp/out.mail
$ uuencode file3.tar.gz file3.tar.gz >> /tmp/out.mail
$ cat email-body.txt >> /tmp/out.mail
$ mail -s "$1" ops@mydomain.com < /tmp/out.mail
```

Hope the above helps.